# Sub set data frame with highest row value

Tags: r

Consider the data frame:

```
a=1
b=3
c=4
df=data.frame(a,b,c)
row.names(df)<-"x"

Preview:
    ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
    ║   ║ a ║ b ║ c ║
    ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣
    ║ x ║ 1 ║ 3 ║ 4 ║
    ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
maxn <- function(n) function(x) order(x, decreasing = TRUE)[n]
highest<- apply(df, 1, function(x)x[maxn(1)(x)])
```

This is the output that it produces:

```
 > highest
    x 
    4
```

What I need is the row name and column names as well:

```
  c
x 4
```

Comment: Do you want to have the largest value in each row of the data.frame, or the largest value within the entire data.frame? If your data.frame will consist only of one row (as in the example), the distinction is unimportant.

Comment: Max value across all columns, where the data frame has only one row.
So that equates to highest value in data frame in this case.

Comment: If you have only one row, `df[which.max(df)]` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[apply(df,1,which.max)]
```